# How to access the value of a Model in Laravel through Controller?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get an 'id' of the table where 'user_id' == auth()->id() (checks what row belongs to user).

here's what I accomplished so far:

- In the Controller with this line I'm trying access 'id' of Clients table where...
  `'client_id' => Clients::select('id')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->get()`
- Once Controller is triggered it gets the 'id' as an object and tries to insert into DB as:
  `[ { "id": 1 } ]`

What would be an overcome to this, so I can get only 'id' value in return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` will returned a collection. You can use instead `first()` then you have directly access to the Model. Afterwards you can append `->id`. It will return only the client id.

`'client_id' => Clients::select('id')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->first()->id;`

```
// output the id as int
```